# Apache supposedly ignoring htaccess directive?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !admin\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [G]

RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

What is should do, is if the file is a valid file nothing should happen (the file should be processed normally) - this WORKS.

Next, if the file has a .php extension, but isn't admin.php, then it should return a 410 Gone status. This doesn't work - it always goes to the next directives, and the second block is ignored.

Example URL: `http://<my site>/file.php` - doesn't return 410, goes to the last directive.

Why is this happening?

(Also, I don't think stackoverflow is the site for this question, but I couldn't think of what is :/)

EDIT: I should probably point out that this works fine on my Windows localhost, but not on my live linux server.

EDIT2: It still doesn't work on my live box with the dot escaped. If I move the second block above the first, everything is goned.

Comment: you forgot to escape the period in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .php$`

Comment: @PatrickEvans unfortunately, it still doesn't work even after escaping the dot :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the .htaccess file in one of the user directories?  If so, then the problem may be that you need to specify AllowOverride in your apache configuration.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html for more info.

Comment: the rewrites are being processed, as he says some of the rewrites work while others do not. None of them would work if the AllowOverride was wrong

Answer (score 0):

`http://<my site>/file.php` isn't giving `GONE` message because you have this rule before:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Which means ignore .htaccess rule for a real file, link or directory. If you want GONE message to appear for `.php` files then exclude this skip rule for `.php` file like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: The files don't exist.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment. Which file doesn't exist?

Comment: The php file the domain is going to. They don't exist, so the first bunch of directives shouldn't match.

Comment: For a non-existing file `Gone` error should definitely appear. Try changing G to F and see 403 - Forbidden error appears or not.